# FromView and Javascript function Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi i Have a problem with the FindControl Instruction in a FormView: when I try to find a control I obtain the following expression:
**"object reference not set to an instance of an object"**
The problem is that this control is in "EditMode" but the formView start in a "ReadOnly" (and it must start in this mode).
How I can use a Javascript function that needs to find control in a "EditMode" state?
thanks

`var valore = document.getElementbyId('<%=FormView1.FindCOntrol("valore_pratica").CliendID%>') ;`

Comment: Could you post your code, it would be helpful.

Comment: I added the code in the question

Comment: Please ensure that the control you are finding by calling FindControl exists in the page.